# Search for a table in multiple schema or databases

Tags: database, search, db2, schema

I have few database names, and each database has many schema,
1. how can I search for a table among database names, OR among schema...any gui or commands ?

Answer (score 0):

what is your RDBMS ?
if it is Oracle just try something like this: "schemaname.tablename"
if it is MSSQL try this "schemaname.databasename.tablename"

Answer (score 0):

You need to query the DB2 catalog when connected to a database

```
SELECT TABSCHEMA, TABNAME FROM SYSCAT.TABLES WHERE TABNAME LIKE 'MYTABLE%'
```

This can work from the GUI or CLP.

You can mix the previous command in a bash script that connects to all database of an instance

```
db2 list db directory | awk ... | source /dev/stdin
```

Or even, in all databases of all instances

```
db2ilist | awk ... | source /dev/stdin
db2greg -dump | awk ... | source /dev/stdin
```

If you are using Windows, you can do something similar with PowerShell.

In the following project, you can see some scripts in bash that do similar things: https://github.com/angoca/db2admintools/tree/master/exec